# How much can the Pearson and Spearman correlation coefficients differ in a dataset? (edited)

Tags: pearson-r, spearman-rho

Probably this has been asked and answered before, but I could not find an answer. It can also be, that I don't find an answer, because it is not a meaningful question.

Nevertheless, I would be interested in a set of data with Pearson correlation above 0.95 and Spearman correlation below 0.6.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to have a set of data w/ those values, or have you seen one & want to know how to interpret that?

Comment: I have not seen one like that, I am asking whether this is possible or not.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by a "linear" or "monotonic" relationship?  The reason why this needs elaboration is plain in some of the answers you are receiving, which exhibit scatterplots that are obviously neither linear nor monotonic.  The issue is whether you are asking about *data* or a *regression model.*

Comment: @whuber I am not sure how to do this. I do not think it is appropriate to change the title, although as I explained in my comment to the answer by Alexis, it would have been better to ask "Can a relationship measured to be strongly linear but not strongly monotonic?" I think, the text of the question is clear. I was looking for an example set of data with very specific Pearson and Spearman correlation coefficients. The answers I get are to this specific question. The reason I did not accept either of them, because they all give different perspectives.

Comment: That's precisely the problem: vague questions get varying answers depending on the interpretations.  That doesn't work out well in most instances: it confuses people and may even lead to extensive misunderstanding.  By clarifying the text and/or the title you can help people understand what the intended interpretation is.

Comment: @whuber Can you explain to me what is vague about the text itself?

Comment: I did: it isn't clear what you mean by a "relationship" or even by "linear."  Are you implicitly equating the meanings of "monotonic" and "linear" with the Spearman and Pearson correlation coefficients, respectively?  If so, are you referring to the coefficients in the underlying model or in the data?  The answers clearly use different senses of "linear" and "monotonic," which is why some of them disagree.

Comment: No you did not. You explained why my title is vague. I agree. But titles are not to explain the full question. The question is very specific and clear. It may not have strong connections to the title, but nevertheless, it is a clear specific question and people answered to that clear, specific question. People, who wanted to understand the question did, and answered it.

Comment: And the fact that they answered the question in different ways is *prima facie* evidence of its ambiguity.

Comment: @whuber, can you please tell me what would be an acceptable title for you for the question I asked in the post itself: "I would be interested in a set of data with Pearson correlation above 0.95 and Spearman correlation below 0.6." ?

Comment: Looking over the answers, I see two of them responded to "linear/monotonic" dichotomy in the title and three responded to the question about correlation coefficients. Perhaps the best thing you can do at this point, then, is to alter the title to match the question.  Something a little more open-ended than stipulating values of 0.95 and 0.6, like "How much can the Pearson and Spearman correlation coefficients differ in a dataset?", might be the most helpful for understanding your intentions.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I edited the title. However, I would like to point out, that this difference between title/text was exactly what I was mentioning in my reply to your very first comment and also in my comment in flagging this question for moderator attention that was promptly ignored.

Comment: That's right, and for good reason: material that appears only in comments usually is ignored.  Comments have second class status here.  To be on topic, the *question itself* must stand alone and be sufficiently consistent and understandable to be unambiguously answered.  As soon as you created those conditions for an answerable question, it was reopened.  But some damage has been done: at least two of the posted answers do not address the question.

Comment: We can argue about this all year long. Moderators, who censor questions should not ignore answer to their concern which themselves put as a comment. We would not be in this situation if you would have answered my very first reply in a more positive way. The "damage" is partly done by me by not being careful with the title, but partly done by you not replying constructively for a long time. If you go up and read my first comment, it does say I am not sure what to do and it does include a possible title change.

Answer (score 8):

Sure.  We can achieve this result by adding a single extreme data point to an otherwise uncorrelated, and nonmonotonically related, set of data:

```
x <- c(rnorm(99), 100)
y <- c(rnorm(99), 100)

> cor(x,y,method="pearson")
[1] 0.990387
> cor(x,y,method="spearman")
[1] 0.02534653
```

Note that the first 99 values are uncorrelated with each other according to either definition of the term, but the 100th value is extreme.  This causes the Pearson correlation coefficient to be large, but the  Spearman correlation is less affected, as the rank of the largest value is 1 regardless of how large the value itself is.

Compare to a less extreme outlier:

```
x[100] <- 10
y[100] <- 10

> cor(x,y,method="pearson")
[1] 0.5148878
> cor(x,y,method="spearman")
[1] 0.02534653
```

And a plot:

[image]

Comment: It’s possible to make this even weirder by giving a strong linear trend downward on that cluster of points. The Spearman will be strongly negative while Pearson is strongly positive!

Comment: Nice illustration of the leverage effect in regression/correlation.

Answer (score 4):

An (less extreme) example without outlier is

```
x <- 1:200
y <- c(rep(0, 50), rep(1, 100), rep(2, 50))  - 0.001 * x

plot(y ~ x, type = "s")
cor(x, y)               # 0.90
cor(x, y, method = "s") # 0.69
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a linear relationship between $Y$ and $X$ without adding an additive interaction with at one additional variable creating the shifts in the intercept. Indeed the positive Pearson;s $r$ that must result from such a graph belies the *negative* association between $Y$ and $X$ which would result from conditioning on that/those other variables.

Answer (score 2):

**Part I. No: Linearity is *one* example of [monotonicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function).**

A monotonic relationship between $Y$ and $X$ means "$Y$ never decreases as $X$ increases, but only increases or remains constant" (for positive monotonicity), or "$Y$ never increases as $X$ increases, but only decreases or remains constant" (for negative monotonicity). A positive linear relationship between $Y$ and $X$ fits the former relationship, and a negative linear relationship between $Y$ and $X$ fits the latter.

While we cannot validly infer that "monotonicity implies linearity" in precisely the same way that we cannot infer that "food implies apples," we *can* infer that "linearity implies monotonicity" in the same way that "apples imply food."

Correspondingly, a lack of monotonicity implies a lack of linearity, but a lack of linearity *does not* imply a lack of monotonicity.

**Part II. Pearson's $r$ is a fragile measure of linearity**

Pearson's $r$ is subject to particular assumptions in order to produce estimates which have reliable interpretations. For example, violation of the homoscedasticity assumption (familiar from linear regression) can produce more or less *any* value of $r$ in uncorrelated data (i.e. in data with no linear, and no monotonic relation) with the simple addition of a *high leverage* data point which is (1) an extreme value in the $X$ dimension, and (2) has a value of $Y$ for that extreme value of $X$ including some non-zero slope on the linear regression between $Y$ and $X$. In this way, you can obtain an arbitrarily strong (and invalid) estimate of linearity, with an arbitrarily weak Spearman's $r_{\text{S}}$.

Comment: Probably I was not careful enough phrasing the title. I was looking for an example that is given in the answer by @jbowman . Probably I should have asked "Can a relationship be measured to be much more linear than monotonic?" And apparently (contrary to my intuition) it can.

Comment: @FerencBeleznay Please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot add comments comments right now, so I added this as a new answer.
Alexis is totally right, that there can't be linearity without monotonicity. However, it is still possible to get a higher Pearson than Spearman correlation coefficient.

Just correlate  1,2,3,1000000 wit 5,4,3, 1000000.

 The Pearson coefficient is close to 1, while the Spearman correlation coefficient is only 0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of trend with seasonality data will fit your description. For instance, CPI not seasonally adjusted will have a strong linear trend, but CPI increase over time is clearly non-monotonic due to annual seasonality.

[image]

Comment: Not sure that the trend is "clearly linear" for *exactly* the same reasons that your describe the trend as "clearly non-monotonic." (I.e. a *monotonic* trend will not shift up and down, but likewise a *linear* trend will also not shift up and down; put another way: if you can blur your eyes on that curve to see *linear*, then you have already blurred your eyes enough to see *monotonic*).

Comment: The time trend is upwards, and could appear linear. It has to be, it's prices. Yet the increase over time is not monotonic.

Comment: "The time trend is upwards, and could appear linear. It has to be, it's prices" <—You have just made the argument that the *trend* in price is monotonically increasing.